# Struggling with "NULL" FromAddress in EmailMessage Before-Insert Trigger from Outlook Integration

Tags: email, before-trigger, outlook

I am trying to create a before-insert trigger on EmailMessage, so that when a user logs an email from the Outlook Integration, I can set the RelatedToId field based on the email sender (FromAddress).

What I am finding in my testing, however, is that both FromAddress and ValidatedFromAddress are NULL on insert! Perhaps due to how the Outlook Integration inserts email records - perhaps it follows up the insert with an update to populate the FromAddress field.

Unfortunately, I must put my logic in the before-insert - you are only allowed to set RelatedToId on insert.

(1) Do any of you have more details around the behavior of the Outlook Integration and the From fields that might help me?

(2) Can anyone see another solution to be able to programmatically set the RelatedToId for tracked emails, based on the sender, other than my approach of the before-insert trigger on EmailMessage?

I have considered moving my logic to an after insert, and trying to delete the original email and recreate it with all the right information, but that seems extreme and I am concerned about the impact the changing id (due to delete and create new) will have on the Outlook Integration.

Thanks to all for any help you can provide!

Scott Kostojohn